# Grouping by a Pandas dataframe and putting column back

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlite

I have the following pandas dataframe:

[image]

I want to replicate the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT
cars, 
city, 
CASE WHEN miles_travelled=100 THEN SUM(complaints)/SUM(calls) ELSE 0 END as ratio
FROM table
GROUP BY cars, city
```

Here's the closest I've been:

```
table.groupby(['cars','city','miles_travelled'])['complaints','calls'].sum()
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: From SQL perspective, this is not a valid aggregation query to start with. `miles_travelled` is in the `select` clause but not in the `group by` clause.

Comment: miles_travelled is not in the select clause. Its in the case statement, which is aggregated

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL `CASE` method, so do you want `miles_travelled` to be another index in the grouped dataframe (have ratio values for every combination of cars, city AND miles_traveled) or do you just want a ratio value for every combination of just cars and city, but the aggregated value of ratio does not include the complaints/calls where miles_travelled = 100?

In either case, you might be better adding a ratio column then conducting the grouped aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make `ratio` for just combinations of `city` and `cars` and ignore the cases as the quotient of the sum of `complaints` and `calls` ignoring rows where `miles_travelled` is 100 then this will work.

```
# filter to ignore rows where miles_travelled = 100
(table[table['miles_travelled'] != 100]
 # groupby city and cars and select the complaint and calls columns
 .groupby(['city','cars'])['complaints','calls']
 # sum the selected columns
 .agg(sum)
 # make the ratio column which is the sum of complaints / sum of calls
 .assign(ratio = lambda x: x['complaints'] / x['calls']))
```